# How to get the property name from the property in data contract

Tags: datacontracts

I have a datacontract and in that i want to get the name of a property as mentioned in the code below.

```
 [DataMember]
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Now i am passing the values as

```
    void GetMethod()
{

// takes PropertyName and Property values

ValidateMe("PhoneNumber", phoneObj.PhoneNumber.ToString();

}
```

Now i need to pass instead get the Property Name instead of Hardcoded "PhoneNumber"

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string GetPropertyName<TValue>(Expression<Func<TValue>> propertyId)
{
   return ((MemberExpression)propertyId.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

By this way we can retrieve the Property Name